# How can i check lock screen notifcation is enabled or not programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, settings

I want to check that user has enabled lock screen notifications or not.
Settings -> Notifications -> Lock Screen Notifications

But I am not able to find any code regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this:

```kotlin
fun getLockscreenNotificationsEnabled(context: Context) =
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.getInt(
        context.contentResolver,
        "lock_screen_show_notifications", 0
    ) != 0
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much.